# How to make glass material more "Reflective" / "shiny"

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

So I have a scene where I want it to be raining.

It is a room with 2 windows, the camera points to the windows and looks out. The surrounding buildings are faked by a box enclosing the room. A plane with an emitter particle system generates the raindrops. The materials have *Backface Culling* enabled so you see the room. The room is closed, the surrounding box has no ceiling.

I have 3 point lights below the rain and above the ground, so it's like a street light and I also have a dim sum light (strength is .5 and the color is dark). Also, I tried adding an HDRI but for some reason, it always appears as light pink.

[image: image 1]

Problem is, (I think) the environment is dark so the raindrops are not that visible.

The material used for the rain is just a glass BSDF with glossy BSDF (0 roughness) mixed with a mix shader with a factor of 0.8.

How do I make the raindrops more visible?

Also, the raindrops are the slightly dark grey tint on the picture.

The camera view of the window:

[image: image 2]

blend file (I forgot to switch the render engine to cycles so you have to change if when you download the file)
[image]

Comment: Hello, are you in Eevee? In that case it's better to have an HDRI or some lights to have something to reflect, or you need to use a Light Probe and Bake Indirect Lights in order to have something, maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: I'm in cycles. Though, I'm trying to get results similar to Eevee

Comment: And how did you set up the lighting? Do you use an HDRI? (for some reason people only answer the first question even if there are 2 or more in the comments ;-)

Comment: I have 3 point lights below the rain and above the ground so it's like a street light and I also have a dim sum light (strength is .5 and the color is dark). Also, I tried adding a HDRI but for some reason it always appear as light pink.

Comment: Maybe pack your images and share your file (at least a part of it) so that we can test? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Pink light means that the HDR image is missing for some reason. You need to set it in the world shader settings.

Comment: 1.Alright I already added the blend file

2.I downloaded an image from HDRhaven and the file type is .EXR then it doesn't work when I added an image texture to the world lighting. Converted it to .HDR and PNG and still the same. Though, if I open the image from photoshop everything seems to be fine.

3.Can my window perhaps be the cause of this issue I'm having?

Comment: For the HDRI: you need an Environment Texture node instead of an Image Texture node. //EDIT: Where did you add the .EXR? There's nothing in your file in the world lighting.

Comment: Ok, turns out i needed environment texture. Also I removed the .EXR because I thought it failed. But even if I added an environment texture, the raindrops are still not that visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out I can decrease the IOR of the glass material to something much lower. Even if it doesn't look too good, is still got the job done.

Comment: Just in case that you want more raindrops on the window have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233531/looping-rain-on-window-effect